# Is using SSL session cache a bad idea for a websocket server?

Tags: session, caching, ssl, openssl, websocket

When a client reconnects to an SSL server, SSL session caches remove the need to recompute the same cryptographic agreement previously used by that client (while also reducing the communication round trips needed from 2 to 1).

However, the websocket protocol states that clients should never disconnect from a websocket server without a good reason (e.g. because an error occurred or the user closed the browser/application tab/window) (?); so when websockets are established on top of an SSL layer, the server can simply assume any websocket connection is alive unless notified otherwise, during which time the underlying SSL session of any connection can also safely be assumed to remain valid?

Furthermore, a websocket server needs to be able to handle many concurrent long lived connections, and because SSL session caches need to be stored for every single connection (?), implementing these caches would in this case probably be detrimental to performance because of the large memory overhead, right?

Sorry; this might be more than one simple question, but I wanted to verify if my understanding of these issues is adequate.

Comment: There is only one SSL session cache. SSL sessions are stored in the cache per session, not per connection. Multiple simultaneous connections from the same client use the same session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

I think it might depend on the software architecture. Let's say you have a site with 100 pages and the user often navigates between them. Many of them have a websocket for some special purpose, but it is only kept alive during the display of that page. Then caching would make sense as you're closing/opening WebSockets often.

On the other hand, you might have a site whit only one page and where you open a websocket. Content is managed by WebSocket and Ajax requests, but the WebSocket is kept alive during the whole session. In this case, caching SSL for the WebSocket doesn't make much sense.

So, at the end, I would say it depends on the implementation. If you already have a site, you should analyze how it behaves and tune your cache needs. On the other hand, if you're starting to design a new site, knowing pros and cons of different scenarios might help you to build a better and more efficient design.

Regards

Comment: Thanks. I had the scenario of your second paragraph in mind, but failed to mention that in my question. Good point.